# 5 ampere to 15 ampere

Tags: switch

I want to ask two questions done go on title. I'm from India.

1. Can I connect 15 ampere switch in 5 ampere socket.
2. If I want to replace a 5 ampere socket to 15 ampere will the 15 ampere socket work properly for with the same input wire used for 5 ampere socket.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in your first question.  Are you asking if you can use a switch rated for 15A in a 5A rated circuit?

Comment: I don't know Indian electrical outlets specifically, but many outlets (sockets) have different shapes for different amp loads and you will not be able to put a 5 A plug in a 15 A socket.

Comment: @Comintern Yes, I want you know that in my first question

Comment: Are your switches fused switches? You don't want to remove any safety protection that prevents more than 5 amps from going on the wiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes but No.

   You can plug into a 5A socket an appliance or lead that contains a switch rated at 15A.

   You can use a 15A switch to turn on/off an appliance rated at 5A.

   However the appliance connected must not draw more than 5A - it's rating must not exceed 5A.
2. No

   You cannot normally increase the rating of a socket without running a thicker wire back to the main fusebox/consumer-unit.